# Uploading array with angular: how to get errors from the backend?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have a very simple Angular application that is sending a list of strings (just for this example, in reality it is a list of more complex data called protocols) to a backend/server (a MS AspNetCore application written in C#) using the post method. This functionality is working fine, but as I am very new to angular I am struggling to handle failures during this process, that occurred on the server side. I want to display a error message in the client if something goes wrong.

Here is what I built so far by orienting on the angular tutorial:
The angular **component.ts** file basically has a upload method:

```
constructor(
    private readonly SVC: UploadService) { }

uploadStringlist(): void {
    let sarray: string[] = [];

    sarray.push("string1");
    sarray.push("string2");

    this.SVC.uploadList(sarray).subscribe(
     _ => { this.finished,emit(`protocols sent: next`)},
     err => { this.finished.emit(`Protocols sent: error` + err)},
     () => { this.finished.emit(`Protocols sent`)});
}
```

and the **upload.service.ts** file basically has this method:

```
uploadList(slist: string[]): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.post<string>(apiurl, slist, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap(res => log("uploaded protocol list to server", res)),
      catchError(handleError<string>("test")));
}
```

The piping is just something in for completeness (I do not want to change my example too much from the original code)

So and on the server side there is just this uploadController:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(string[] slist)
{
    foreach (var s in slist)
    {
       // do something
    }

    return StatusCode(409);
    //return Ok();
}
```

So, and no matter what I return on the controller, I get the same result in the client. Which means I get the result: "protocols sent".

But ideally I would get a list of results (one for each entry in the string array) or at least an error if I return an error in the controller.
But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ModelState` to keep a pattern in error handling in your controllers, this way you will be sure that all errors returns will have the same structure.

Using `ModelState` with the `BadRequest` method will insure that your `ModelState` will be fiiled into your `err` variable on your code: `err => { this.finished.emit('Protocols sent: error' + err)},`

This is simple example based on your code.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(string[] slist)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var s in slist)
        {
           // do something
           if(NotValid(s))
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your message to the client");
           }
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        return Ok(new { successMessage = "success"});
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log your exception
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your generic error message");
        ModelState.AddModelError("SomeProperty", "Your error message about 'SomeProperty'");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

in your client side you will need to change this line:

```
catchError(handleError<string>("test")));
```

to something like this:

```
catchError(error => handleError<any>(error)));
```

You can learn more about `ModelState` on de docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: And how is this handled on the client side? I fear that the way i just subscribe to the upload method in the service is not sufficient enough..

Comment: I just updated the answer with the client side changes. Once you return a status code >= 400 on the server your client will automaticly knows that an error occours. Than you just need to handle it on the `catchError` of your `.post` method

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to see the error is to throw an `exception`, for example:

```cs
throw new ArgumentException("Something bad happened.");
```

Also in case of Web API projects make sure that you have turned on error reporting(but when going to production turn it back off) from `web.config` file:

```xml
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```